# Background accumulated tasks executed periodically

Tags: android, web-services, scheduled-tasks

I am devolping an Android App that need to execute an accumulation of internet tasks periodically (like a web bot). Those tasks need to get stored at a specific time so I thought about using Alarm Manager and a
embeded Database. Due to it, the app could be active much more time, although those save tasks do not need web connection. Later I will throw another Alarm Manager to execute all the tasks queued and do web stuff.

Otherwise I am not sure if it is better to use a foreground service. The app will be working all the day saving the tasks (each 5 or 15 min) but only running task queue with internet  each 30mins.

I feel capable of developing both systems but I would like to know which one is better in terms of performance, of battery consumption.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Only a recommendation try to find and use a nice library to do it, every Android Update change something about foreground/background servicess.
one is
[TimedDog](https://github.com/devmike01/TimedDog?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=8029)
and for more
[enter link description here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/9?sort=created)

Comment: I would prefer to use a library as you recommend. That is why I though about using Alarm Manager to schedule tasks and insert the execution of WorkManager inside the alarm (both Android recommendations). On the other side I do not know if using a foreground server is the same but managing all configurations.